# How do I get one value from an SQL query in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I get the first result of this query using php? I want the first result that is returned when the list is in descending order.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT orderID FROM orders WHERE 'customerID' = '".$_SESSION['accountID']."' ORDER BY
                    'orderID' DESC";
                $lastorder = mysqli_query($sql2);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `LIMIT 1` to the end of your SQL

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT`:

```
'SELECT orderID FROM orders WHERE customerID = "' . $_SESSION['accountID'] . '" ORDER BY orderID DESC LIMIT 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The query:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(orderID) as orderID
            FROM orders 
            WHERE customerID = '" . $_SESSION['accountID'] . "'";
```

If customerID is a number then the single quotes can be removed to make the query:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(orderID) as orderID
            FROM orders 
            WHERE customerID = " . $_SESSION['accountID'];
```

Then...

```
// include database_link since you are not using OO-style call.
$result = mysqli_query($database_link, $query); 
$row = $result->fetch_object();
$orderID = $row->orderID;
```